# How to change an array of chars with the lines of a file?

Tags: c

NOTE: I am a beginner so I don't know plenty of stuff.

The code is working fine. Its purpose is to translate a text file from language one (English) to language 2 (French) using the dictionary from language 1(char word[][]) and language 2(char replace[][]).

I just want to know how I could change it so I am using the line from a text file instead of the "word" and "replace" arrays.

Content of the "word" text file (let's say englishwords.txt):

Hello (this is going to be on the first line of the text)
What (this is going to be on the second line of the text)
You're (this is going to be on the third line of the text)
How are you (this is going to be on the fourth line of the text)
a fool (this is going to be on the fifth line of the text)

Content of the "replace" text file (let's say frenchwords.txt):

Salut (this is going to be on the first line of the text)
Quoi (this is going to be on the second line of the text)
Tu es (this is going to be on the third line of the text)
Ce va (this is going to be on the fourth line of the text)
un fou (this is going to be on the fifth line of the text)

Basically: one line in the text file = one word or correlated phrase

```
int main(){
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
char fname[MAX];
char string[MAX];
char temp[] = "temp.txt", *ptr1, *ptr2;

/* get the input file from the user */
printf("Enter your input file name: ");
fgets(fname, MAX, stdin);
fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0';

int j = NULL;
do {

    /* in-code dictionary */

    char word[MAX][MAX] =
    {
        "Hello",
        "What",
        "You're", 
        "How are you",
        "a fool"
    };


    char replace[MAX][MAX] =
    {
        "Salut",
        "Quoi",
        "Tu es",
        "Ca va",
        "un fou"
    };

    /* open input file in read mode */
    fp1 = fopen(fname, "r");

    /* error handling */
    if (!fp1) {
        printf("\nUnable to open the input file or it doesn't exist!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* open temporary file in write mode */
    fp2 = fopen(temp, "w");

    /* error handling */
    if (!fp2) {
        printf("\nUnable to open temporary file or it was erased!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* going through and replacing the objects */

    j++;
    while (fgets(string, sizeof string, fp1)) {
        char *p = string;
        int i;
        while (*p) {
            for (i = NULL; i < 5; ++i)
                if (!strncmp(p, word[i], strlen(word[i])))
                    break;
            if (i < 5) {
                fputs(replace[i], fp2);
                p += strlen(word[i]);
            }
            else {
                putc(*p, fp2);
                p++;

            }
        }

    }


    /* close the opened files */
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    /* remove the input file */
    remove(fname);

    /* rename temporary file name to input file name */
    rename(temp, fname);

} while (j < 2);

return NULL;}
```

I guess this is how I start:

FILE *enw = fopen("englishwords.txt", "r");

FILE *frw = fopen("frenchwords.txt", "r");

But how do I do continue the resolve?

Comment: You should probably read in the dictionary file into a map and then use that map to replace values as you read them in and write to a file.

Comment: `fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0';` This code is always pointless.  How do you think `strlen()` finds the end of your string?  `fgets()` will always nul-terminate.

Comment: Side note: what is MAX? Why are you using MAX for both indizes (first and second)?  One index is for the maximum number of words and the other is for the maximum length of each word. I'd be surprised if both are identical. Regarding reading the file into `word` or `replace`: what is your question about that? You seem to know how to `fgets`!?

Comment: @FatalError it is (a bad way )for removing the '\n'

Comment: a good way to remove a '\n':   `fname[ strcspn(fname) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `printf("\nUnable to open temporary file or it was erased!\n")`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  and when the error indication is from a C library function (like `fopen()`) should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  for non-C library errors use: `fprintf( stderr, "my error message\n" );`   For C library errors use: `perror( "my error message" );`

Comment: @Rietty The only issue is that I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: @WernerHenze I know about fgets, but I don't know how to implement it in this situation...

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you a lot for reviewing my code! I will change it as adviced.

Comment: regarding this kind of statements: `return NULL;`  in the function: `main()`, it returns an `int`, not a pointer to 0 (NULL).  A better way to exit the `main()` function, when there is an error is `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the header file: `stdlib.h`